# a function returning the opposite of a number

Tags: python, variables, floating-point, integer, user-defined-functions

I'm training with codewars for an upcoming bootcamp and am asked to write a simple user defined function. It passes the first four tests, but fails the last two. The challenge is posed as:

*Very simple, given a number, find its opposite.
Examples:
1: -1
14: -14
-34: 34*

I wrote the following code

```
def opposite(number):
    if number > 0:
        return (-number)
    elif number < 0:
        return (+number)
    else: 
        return 0
```

However, I run into problems with the last two tests

```
    test.assert_equals(opposite(1),-1)
    test.assert_equals(opposite(25.6), -25.6)
    test.assert_equals(opposite(0), 0)
    test.assert_equals(opposite(1425.2222), -1425.2222)
  * test.assert_equals(opposite(-3.1458), 3.1458)
  * test.assert_equals(opposite(-95858588225),95858588225)
```

I remember reading something about floats and how the variable is stored as something slightly different than what it appears on the screen, but I don't know what to do to combat this.

Comment: Mere `-number` is enough for all cases

Comment: The second `return` could be `return (+(abs(number))`.

Comment: Thank you Eric Postpischil and Martheen. Would either of you know why this question is a -2 points at the time of writing this? It’s a sincere question. Just need to know if I should change my approach or format. Thanks again

Comment: @NateBates: Your question is voted down likely because it is judged not to be useful to other people because the solution is obvious and because the problem could have been easily diagnosed by testing yourself.

Comment: Okay, thanks for taking the time to answer that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The arithmetic inverse of *x* is −*x*. Therefore, the problem can be solved with:

```
def opposite(number):
    return -number
```

Comment: And here I thought I was keeping it simple. Thanks Eric Postpischil, that works perfectly

Comment: forgot to mark your answer correct. I just did now. Thanks again for your help, your answer works great